# Excel VBA table entry validation

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table created in excel (named WaterTable) and have a userform which allows data to be entered into it.  The columns are: YEAR, QUARTER, SOURCE, VOLUME.

Looking around on here and other locations I have managed to get sorted with code that allows users to enter data into the boxes on the form and submit - with the code adding a new row and entering their data.

However, where I am struggling is that at the moment a user could put in:

```
YEAR - QUARTER - SOURCE - VOLUME
2013 -    4    -  MAINS -   50
```

And that's no problem - BUT if they enter a wrong number and want to re-enter it will just create a new line, but retain the original entry.  This causes problems for presenting the data (multiple entries) and also means errors cannot be corrected.  I have managed to look around and put the following code in:

```
    Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")
    Set table = sheet.ListObjects.Item("WaterTable")
    Set EvalRange = table.DataBodyRange

If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(EvalRange, YearBox.Text) > 1 And WorksheetFunction.CountIf(EvalRange, QuarterBox.Text) > 1 And WorksheetFunction.CountIf(EvalRange, SourceBox.Text) > 1 Then
    MsgBox "Data Entry Already Present"
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Else
    Call AddDataRow
End If
```

Which partially solves my problem - as now you can only enter one 'volume' data point for a particular year, quarter and source.  Which works to an extent - but what I really want is for the message box to give option to either replace the current data OR close.  So that wrongly entered data can be corrected.  Unfortunately I've come across a brick wall on that one and can't think what to use!

Hope that makes sense!

AS ADDITION FOLLOWING COMMENT MADE BELOW:

I've changed to using 'find' command, and come up with the following code to start me off:

```
SearchString = YearBox.Value
On Error Resume Next
Set bCell = oRange.Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, 3)
If Not bCell Is Nothing Then
       MsgBox "Checking data Validity"
    ReplaceData = bCell.Address
End If

Set aCell = oRange.Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
    FoundAt = aCell.Address
   Select Case MsgBox("The entered exists: " & FoundAt & "   " & ReplaceData & "  Replace?", vbYesNo)
    Case vbNo
    MsgBox "data entry cancelled"
    Case vbYes
    Select Case MsgBox("This will replace data: Are You Sure?", vbYesNo)
        Case vbYes
        bCell = VolBox.Value
        Case vbNo
        Call CommandButton1_Click
    End Select
End Select
Else
    MsgBox "Unique Data Entry Confirmed - submit data?", vbOKCancel
    Call AddDataRow
End If
```

Not terribly elegant unfortunately (and I don't know why the first 'find' for bCell fails if the entry is not found - although the aCell which seems to be virtually the same works fine?? Hence the resume on error).

This however will only check one data point (in this case year) so I can find out if the year column matches and then make a change to the volume data if the user wants to or stop if they don't.  What I can't do is use multiple criteria.  I don't see a way to have 'AND' with this?

Comment: What you are looking for is called Add/Modify functionality. For this you can use `.Find` to check for existing record and then retrieve the row number of the found cell so that you can write to the respective row. [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) will get you started. Give it a try and if you get stuck then we will take it form there.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I had a look into that - and that looks a little more like what I need - I can get it to search for a specific data point and change (or not) that point, but not for multiple critera?  (i.e. I can find when the year OR Quarter match the entered data, but not find the row when BOTH match).

Comment: see comments I've added on this to main question

Answer (score 0):

Think I might have solved it (albeit in a slightly clumsy way!)

I've added a hidden column to my table generated from data entry by:

```
lastRow.Cells(1, 1) = YearBox.Text & "-" & QuarterBox.Text & "-" & SourceBox.Text
```

This creates a row which includes the data from all three variables.

I've then modified my search string in the 'find' code I posted in my question to be the same as the above:

```
SearchString = YearBox.Text & "-" & QuarterBox.Text & "-" & SourceBox.Text
```

That way it is only searching one box, but checks all three criteria.

Thanks for the help Siddharth.